# использование id div-ов для блокировки checkbox-ов

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="aaa">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="aaa_1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="aaa_2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3""><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

если отмечен checkbox который находится в div с id aaa_1, блокировался только чекбокс который находится в div с id aaa_2. Как это реализовать с помощию js используя только id div-а?

Comment: А какие такие *определённые* чекбоксы блокировать то надо?

Comment: например, если отмечен checkbox который находится в div с id aaa_1 блокировался только чекбокс который находится в div с id aaa_2

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтобы блокироваться следующий чекбокс, так и надо писать, в будущем пишите конкретную проблему, а не образную задачу которую кроме вас, никто не поймёт. А сейчас, исправьте свой вопрос так, чтобы была понятна задача. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой ["Править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1432526/edit).

Comment: редактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#aaa_1 input').onchange = (e) => {
  let input_2 = document.querySelector('#aaa_2 input');
  input_2.disabled = e.target.checked;
  input_2.checked = false;
}
```

```html
<div id="aaa">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="aaa_1">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="aaa_2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3""><span>text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно также во время блокировки снимать метку? В смысле он блокируется но остается отмеченым.